# Eclipse - not showing variables in debugging mode - tcl

Tags: eclipse, tcl

I am using eclipse IDE on windows with the TCL/ITCL toolkit for coding and debugging my code.

But when I am debugging my code I cannot see any variables at all under the global variable tab.

[image]

I added a screenshot that shows the problem
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Tcl mode provided by [Eclipse DLTK](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.dltk)?

If yes, a variable to become shown as a global variable must be defined as such using the Tcl command [`global`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), e.g.:

```
global x
set x "fsdz"
```

## Impression

This is how my debug perspective (Eclipse Neon.3, DLTK 5.9, Tcl Remote Debubbing 11.1) then looks like:

[image]

Comment: Still I am not seeing any global variable although I updated the code as you described

Comment: Well, see my screenshot and setup details. Works just as expected for me. You will have to provide step-by-step details what you attempted.